# How to show all the content under the parent category?

Tags: drupal

```
category 1
       subcategory 1
       subcategory 2
```

now, when i click the  `category 1` it shows all the contents under subcategory 1 and   subcategory 2. thank you.

but in the default drupal. although there are some contents under  **subcategory 1 and   subcategory 2** when i click **category 1**. it shows there no content....

how to invoke all the content under all the subcategory. thank you.

Comment: the question is really not clear. please try to give more details.

Comment: if you click the parent category it will show all the content which under all the child category?

Comment: drupal defalult state, when you click the  the parent category,it not shows the content belong to the child category

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using Drupal 6, there is a rather simple way to accomplish what you want:

> If you are using a hierarchical taxonomy, and want all nodes tagged with child terms to show up also, you can create an URL link like taxonomy/term/2/2 where the second parameter is the depth that the tree will be recursed into, or taxonomy/term/2/all for all child terms.

(from [About Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/node/774892) page)

But it doesn't work in Drupal 7:

> In D7, you can no longer specify paths such as "taxonomy/term/1,2", "taxonomy/term/1+2","taxonomy/term/2/2" or "taxonomy/term/2/all". Function taxonomy_term_page (D7) does not parse the string as it did in D6.

So, with Drupal 7 you should use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module - you can enable and customize pre-created "Taxonomy term" view (will be available on `admin/structure/views` page right after you enable Views module), or create your own from the scratch.

Also, there is a kind of trick which I've used once before, but it should be used only if you manage a rather small site and you are only one who can add content - just allow to select two items from your vocabulary, and while creating your node choose not only child term but parent term as well.

Comment: if i don't use the views module, how do i do?

Comment: I really don't know how to achieve that without using Views. Anyway, trick from the last paragraph is always available. Not a good practice for sure, but works just fine :)